# NiFi use string manipulation function like padRight in JoltTransformJSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Can we use string manipulation functions like below in JoltTransformJSON

```
${BIG:padRight(5, '@')}
```

Link:
https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-stringFunctions
Expected Output: `BIG@@`

Like we use

```
"small_toUpper": "=toUpper(@(1,small))",
  "BIG_toLower": "=toLower(@(1,BIG))",
```

I am trying but it's not giving any error, but not giving the desired result as well. What would be other alternative for this.

Input JSON:

```json
{
  "x": [
    3,
    2,
    1,
    "go"
  ],
  "small": "small",
  "BIG": "BIG",
  "people": [
    {
      "firstName": "Bob",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "address": {
        "state": null
      }
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Sterling",
      "lastName": "Archer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "y": "=join(',',@(1,x))",
      "z": "=join(' ',@(1,x))",
      "small_toUpper": "=toUpper(@(1,small))",
      "BIG_toLower": "=toLower(@(1,BIG))",
      "BIG_padding": "=padRight(@(5,BIG))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe you have wrong input json or wrong jolt spec. Please edit question and provide both.

Comment: @daggett added input json and spec in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rightPad function along with **modify-xXx-beta** (*xXx*:***default*** or ***overwrite***) transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "BIG_padding": "=rightPad(@(1,BIG),5,'@')"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Ozhan Thanks, rightPad is working fine for me. But, I tried with both modify-default-beta and modify-overwrite-beta. Only modify-overwrite-beta worked for me. Does ordering of "operation"  can be a reason. In my dev i had following operations. 1. "operation": "shift", then 2. "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta", and  3."operation": "shift". I had to add new operator with rightPad between operation 1 and 2

Comment: Hi @likeGreen , both type of transformation will perform the desired operation for this case(`"BIG_padding": "=rightPad(@(1,BIG),5,'@')"`), but if you want to change a key-value pair with already existing key such as `BIG`, then you'll need to use **overwrite** along with `"BIG": "=rightPad(@(1,BIG),5,'@')"`, *this case* **default** won't change the value.